# Trying to avoid shell=True in a Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I need to concatenate multiple files that begin with the same name inside a Python program. My idea, in a bash shell, would be to something like

```
cat myfiles* > my_final_file
```

but there are two shell operators to use: `*` and `>`. This could be easily solved using

```
subprocess.Popen("cat myfiles* > my_final_file", shell=True)
```

but everybody says the using `shell=True` is something you have to avoid for security and portability reasons. How can I execute that piece of code, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to expand the pattern in python:

```
import glob
subprocess.check_call(['cat'] + glob.glob("myfiles*"), stdout=open("my_final_file", "wb"))
```

or better do everything in python:

```
with open("my_final_file", "wb") as output:
    for filename in glob.glob("myfiles*"):
        with open(filename, "rb") as inp:
            output.write(inp.read())
```